# Copy button not working, need to link between 3 pages and can't link its id or value directly

Tags: angularjs, angular

Okay so my problem is that i have 3 seperate .html files 1 which loads in all the components for the overall page the second for the modal, and the third contains the actual input field that i need to get its value from.
The input field is nested inside the modal.

So i need to get the value of the input field, which ng-model is read from the database.
the pagination looks like main.html > importer.html > input.html 
and input.html contains the value's i want, either its id or its value.

I don't expect you to solve my problem for me, i simply need someone to explain or create a snipet to resolve an id or its value in the same structure so i can reproduce it myself.

can't share source code as its licensed, i hope i have given a clear enough explanation for you to understand the concept.

i already tried every stackoverflow or tutorial thats out there, but these all have only 2 compenents/layers which makes it useless to what im doing.

Comment: Please add some ex. code

Answer (score 1):

The kind of question you ask is very specific and vague, which makes it difficult to answer and not very suited for StackOverflow. But I can give a general answer on how to share information across components in Angular: Angular wants you to use [Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

The general idea would be to:

1. Create a service
2. Inject the service in both components that need to send/receive the data
3. Use the service for access to Observables to send/receive data

## 1. Create the service

```
ng generate service my-service
```

## 2. Inject the service

At the top of both components' .ts files:

```
import { MyService } from 'src/app/my-service.ts';
```

In the constructor in both files:

```
construct(
  private svc: MyService
) { }
```

## 3. Use Subjects to transmit events

The general idea of an observable/subject is that the receiver of data can `subscribe` to a stream of events and that the sender can place the `next` value onto the stream. You can use your service to expose such an observable/subject.

In the service:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

class MyService {
  public events$ = new Subject();
}
```

In the receiver's ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.svc.events$.subscribe(
    value => {
      // What should happen with the new value?
    }
  );
}
```

Place this inside of the sending component whenever the value changes for your input field:

```
  this.svc.events$.next(value);
```

PS: You could also simplify this depending on your use-case by using the service to expose a simple variable and depend on Angular's change detection.